# Web Scraping / Getting data from website in Tizen

Tags: javascript, c, xml, web-scraping, tizen

I am absolutely new to Tizen and I would like to develop an app for the Samsung Gear S2 that gives me the current departure times of the bus and tram at several stations in my town. (So that I don't always have to get my phone from the pocket)
So, is it possible that the app sends an HTTP request to the web server where the departures are displayed and then it "scrapes" the specific data which I need? I would prefer the Web application but a Native application (written in C) would be okay as well, if that's not possible with HTML5 and JavaScript.

To make this more clear, the departure times in my case are displayed e.g. for a specific station here: http://old-m.dvb.de/de/abfahrtsmonitor/abfahrten.do?id=33000588
Sorry, it's a German web site but I think you know what I mean. So, I would like to scrape for example the next 10 lines, their destinations and the time of arrival.

Any idea how to do that in Tizen or at least in general?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I didn't know that cross origin requests are allowed in Tizen, so I just made an http request via Ajax and filtered the specific data.

Comment: So follow up your post in Tizen Forum https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/web-scraping-getting-data-website